# Data documentation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and NOSQL databases but have experience with relational database.
Due to the behavior of documents in a collection where a document can have different fields. How can I document the data models ? Anything like ER modeling in Relational Database?
Can you guys share how you do the documentation in your company ?

Thank you.

---

Edit:
I'll try to be more specific, in relational database we use Erwin to document the ER diagram, tables, name of columns, objects, etc...
But I'm having difficult to document the collections and documents in mongodb, mainly for the dynamic of fields in a document.

Comment: UML works fine for MongoDB I use it, why don't you specifically state what you have a problem with, as it stands this question is extremely large and broad

Comment: What do you use for modeling with your RDBMS databases? There are dozens of tools, and questions asking for tools are generally held on StackOverflow.

Comment: If new to MongoDB I would read through the links on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/ as well - they will provide guidance as to how to approach modeling and provides examples.